# How to split a report into multiple PDF files

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba, ms-access-2010

Let's say I have an hundred page report in Access 2010 that includes lists of names (with some other details), grouped by a variable called `NOM_RITIRO`.

I would like to output the report into different PDF files, one for each value of the variable used for grouping.

I was trying to figure out how to make this code work:

```
Sub SplitPdf()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim Source As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFilename As String
MyPath = "D:\Folder\"        

Set db = CurrentDb
SQL = "Select NOM_RITIRO From QueryNominativi Group By NOM_RITIRO"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)    

While Not rs.EOF
    MyFilename = "TK_" & rs!NOM_RITIRO & ".pdf"  
    ' Apply quotes as NOM_RITIRO is a string.
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ElenchiNominativi", acViewPreview, , "NOM_RITIRO = '" & rs!NOM_RITIRO.Value & "'"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, False
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "ElenchiNominativi"
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

I got stuck when I try to run the `DoCmd.OpenReport`. 
I get the message box "Enter parameter Value" like if the recordset is not passing any data

Any idea of what I did wrong?

Comment: Let's say there is always a chance. Show your own effort toward a solution and indicate where the problem is.

Comment: Added solution as an edit to your question.

Comment: @Gustav: sorry but that's not the way to handle closed questions. It has been nominated to be reopened; if enough people agree, you'll be able to post your answer.

Comment: OK, but this looks like plain chicane against the questioneer. Only @Jeeped has left a note, which is the least you could and should do, and none of the close-voters have a badge for ms-access. Also, the question is perfectly clear. Further, the criteria to vote for a close: _too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format_ both fail, which indicates that the close-voters have only little understanding of reporting in Access.

Comment: Sorry guys it's my fault, the question was too vague. I will try to explain me better posting the code

Comment: I guess NOM_RITIRO is numeric, not a string.Try with `"NOM_RITIRO = " & rs!NOM_RITIRO.Value & ""`. Also, you have either to use or not to use the variable `ReportName`. Further, you miss a comma in the syntax for `DoCmd.OutputTo`.

Comment: @Gustav `NOM_RITIRO` is actually a string. I don't really use the var `ReportName`, it was just a 
simplification. Thanks for the missing comma! But in the output i still get only the structure of the report but not the data

Comment: Then try with `DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewReport ... `

Comment: @Gustav Nope still doesn't work... I re edited the code in the orginal message to show you what I'm really using if it can helps...

Comment: OK, then I guess all you miss is the quotes around the value for NOM_RITIRO - see edit.

Comment: Great!!! Now it's working! Gustav you're simply the best, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If NOM_RITIRO is not a field in the recordsource of your report called "ElenchiNominativi" (or mis-spelled) then it will prompt you to enter a parameter value.

Similarly, if the recordsource of your report is a query that contains a fieldname not referenced in any of the tables, you will also get this prompt.